# Checking if user is admin or normal

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo, admin

I am having problems checking whether the user is admin or not in the database. I made it so if admin has the value 1 for the users profile then they are admin and is redirected to the admin page and if not they are redirected to the login page. However I gave my personal account the value of 1 in the database however it is still redirecting me to the login page.

I have given my code below for you to see if I have done anything wrong, please tell me as I have only just started learning PHP.

```
<?php 
session_start();
// First we cubrid_execute(conn_identifier, SQL)te our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("include/common.php"); 

$admin = $_POST['admin'];
$user = $_POST['username'];

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: login.php"); 

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 

// Everything below this point in the file is secured by the login system 

// We can retrieve a list of members from the database using a SELECT query. 
// In this case we do not have a WHERE clause because we want to select all 
// of the rows from the database table. 
$query = " 
    SELECT *
    FROM users 
"; 

try 
{ 
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($admin == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    header("location: memberlist.php");
} 

if ($admin == 0) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: You should limit the query, using a WHERE clause on the username of the current user. Otherwise you won't know which user's admin property you're checking.

Comment: So is `$_SESSION['user']` not empty ->`if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) {header("Location: login.php");}`? Are we to assume `$_POST['admin'] == 1`? You set `$_SESSION['username']`, is `$_SESSION['user']` supposed to be `$_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: You should first check if your $_POST array contains those keys - but never rely on those. Check with a query, whether it's an admin and store the result in your session.

Answer (score 0):

Correct you code First:

Try this:

```
if ($admin == 1) {
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;   //put you admin in session
    header("location: memberlist.php");
} 

if ($admin == 0) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;      //here put your user in session
    header("location: login.php");
}



if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) //if user is empty then it redirects to login page
{ 

    header("Location: login.php"); 


    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 
else if(!empty($_SESSION['admin']))   //if admin is not empty it goes to admin area
{

     header("location: memberlist.php");
}

else if(!empty($_SESSION['user']))   //same here if user is present,then it leads to user area
{


    header("Location: user.php"); 
}
```

Comment: No didnt work :( Everytime I login and then go to the memberlist page I automatically get signed out and moved to the login.php page.

Comment: Unique,your are making code complicated.Try with this script.this will work..easy and simple...if ($row == 1) {
  
    header("location: memberlist.php");
} 

else if ($row == 0) {
   
    header("location: user.php");
}

here is session.php

if(!empty($_SESSION['ID']))   //if id is empty then it redirects to login page


    header("Location:login.php"); 
}

Comment: Yes, and the code you gave, how will the website know if the user is an admin and not a normal user, because looking at the code as you wrote it there, it looks like it is just checking if the user is logged in? I maybe wrong, as i said im new to PHP.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if I made a new table, new query and made it so if the user's account was also in the admin table as well as the normal users table, it will allow them to login to the admin page as well as the normal users page, and normal users cannot login to the admin page?

Comment: Make a table,in which take a column usertype...if admin put 1 in and put 0 for normal user....run query get usertype. $row[usertype], and put ID in session. now write same code as I posted in comment.

Comment: I mean was take column in your existing login table, check this usertype in php if else condition.let me know if you don't understand.